# Getting 0 the Location x,y of TextView

Tags: android, location

I make word puzzle in android. I have a table-layout and 10 rows in table-layout and 10 textview in a row. I have 100 textview in total. I need to get the locations of textview. I tried getLeft()-getTop(), getLocationInWindow(), getLocationOnScreen() but I get always 0.

Example :

```
konumal();

}

    public void konumal() {

        int[] korr = new int[2];

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tablojj)).getLocationInWindow(korr);

        Log.w("Dikkat", "x : " + korr[0] + " y : " + korr[1]);

    }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Which function do I need to use?

I need your help.

Comment: From where  is the method called ? `onCreate()` ?

Comment: @bwt I called function in onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the layout pass to set the position, for example

```
final View mainView = findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_main_view);
mainView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // at this point the views are positionned

        konumal()

        // we don't need to listen anymore
        mainView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank a lot.